# In Java, why don't you have to call the main method?

Tags: java

Every method you create in Java you have to call, for example, say you create a method called myMethod(). In order to executive that method you have to write something like **do** myMethod(). How come you don't have to write **do** main() after you define it? I know it doesn't really matter, but I am very curious.

Comment: Every question matters ^^ if we weren't inquisitive we wouldn't be human.

Comment: What would call the code, `do main()` in your scenario?

Comment: Where would you call it from? Remember that none of your code is running until main is called. So you'd have to call it from outside your program. Well that's what happens and someone already wrote that code for you.

Comment: Who would call the thing that called main if you had to call main, and what would the thing you used to call main be called?

Comment: People, many languages will start executing statements from the start of a file. Java requires boilerplate of classes and methods before allowing statements.

Comment: @TomHawtin if u put ur statements in a static init block the way jesus intended, there is no need for boilerplate

Comment: @emory :) Doesn't work with Java WebStart, IIRC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The runtime invokes it automatically for you, when you execute java and give it a class.

That's why there are very specific requirements for main.  It's special, being the method the runtime looks for when starting up.  It's the entry point into your program.

If there is no proper main method on the class that you try to run, you will get an error.

Comment: if ur clazz has a static init block it does not need a main method. it will run w/out error.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, every class can have main(String... args), it depends on which class is being loaded. It is not must that you have to write a main in java class, however, main comes in handy to do Unit testing.

Coming to the point

"A Java virtual machine starts up by loading a specified class and then invoking the method main in this specified class."

< Java Language Specification > 
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html

However you can call main explicitly aswell.

```
/* Student.java */ 
package stackoverflow;

class Student {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Student called"); 
        Person.main(null);
    }
}

/* Person.java */
package stackoverflow; 

class Person { 

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Person called"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Launching the program calls the main method.

The command line arguments are those of main. `foo a b c` is `main("a","b","c")` (psuedocode)

Answer (score 0):

It's from the main method that control enters your java program and then executes every other function that is called. It's automatically called.